# Why does NSString compare: return NSOrderedSame when the strings are different?

Tags: objective-c

Why does compare return NSOrderedSame?:

```
NSString *testString = [anObject aString];

if ([testString compare:@"a string which doesn't equal testString"] == NSOrderedSame) {
    //do stuff
}
```

NB: I added this question so I won't make this mistake again (hence the immediate answer I gave).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because `testString` can equal `nil`. Sending a message to `nil` returns `nil`. `NSOrderedSame` equals `0`, and `0` equals `nil`.

```
NSLog(@"nil == NSOrderedSame = %d", (nil == NSOrderedSame)); //nil == NSOrderedSame = 1
NSLog(@"[nil compare:@\"arf\"] == nil = %d", ([nil compare:@"arf"] == 0));    //[nil compare:@\"arf\"] == nil = 1
```

To avoid this ensure that the object is not `nil` before comparing, eg:

```
if (testString != nil && [testString compare:@"testString"] == NSSOrderedSame) ...
```

NB: I added this question so I wouldn't make this mistake again.

Comment: This is a really bad idea!  NSString compare documents its parameter as "This value must not be nil".  So that could well crash or do other undesirable things if testString is nil.

Comment: Is this true of caseInsensitiveCompare also?

Answer (score 5):

Probably [anObject aString] returns nil, sending nil a message returns 0, and 0 == NSOrderedSame.